# How to terminate shell on 1st instance of failed command ( search for 1st instance of string and append to it )

Tags: shell, search, sed, awk, ksh

I auto-generate a file using a wrapper that performs a series of commands  in parallel like this

```
C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile1 2>& 1 &    # call is I_1

C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile2 2>& 1 &    # I_2

C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile3 2>& 1 &

C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile4 2>& 1 &
```

The file is automatically generated already by the wrapper process What I'd like to do is this. If I_1 fails then terminate everything I_2 onwards. 
I guess one way of doing this is finding the 1st instance of `2>& 1 &` and removing the '&' at the end to `2>& 1` which will run it in fg  and then add these lines `{ rc= $? && [ "$rc" -ne 0 ] && return $rc ; }` to the following line . So following this - the outcome would look like this

```
C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile1 2>& 1   # removed &
 { rc=$? && [ "$rc" -ne 0 ] && return $rc ; }

C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile2 2>& 1 &    # I_2

C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile3 2>& 1 &

C1 p1 p2 p3  > logfile4 2>& 1 &
```

Some AWK or Sed would do the job . Or is there is a better approach to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this line at the top of your script:

```
set -o errexit
```

This will cause bash to terminate the script on very first command failure.

Comment: Yes but I still have to knock off the 1st `&` lest all commands gets submitted in parallel and the set has no meaning. So got to use this sed `sed -i '0,/2>\&1\&/s/2>\&1\&/2>\&1/' filename` . Hope that makes sense or am I missing something .

Comment: correct so I am firing 12 commands in background or parallel whatever you want to call it. So if one of them has error - everyone has the same error and the set flag wont be effective. It needs to act on a 'test' command it can control 1st. So I used the above to make the 1st go in foreground or am I missing something

Comment: I guess putting command in background is making things different here since calling shell has already started rest of the jobs.

Comment: right so the sed will make the 1st command run in fg - so your set flag is effective - right ? Oh BTW this is ksh not bash . Assume the same set works there - almost certain but just fyi. All this will happen Before the shell is run from the wrapper. Wrapper makes the shell and then runs it